# R reticulate install python libraries from Github

Tags: python, r, github, package, reticulate

Does anyone have any ideas on how to directly install the python libraries available on Github from **reticulate**? The `py_install` function only supports libraries available on **conda** or **PyPI**.

For example, when building an **R** package based on a python library only available on Github, do I inevitably have to copy the source code of the library into my package?

Comment: You can create a git submodule of the python repo in your R package repo.

Comment: @danlooo may you explain better the procedure, please?
assume I would like to install this package: https://github.com/gher-ulg/DivaPythonTools

Comment: Mybe sth like this https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/905

Answer (score 2):

Finally, in the function where I set up the python environment for the package, I called the **R base** `system` function where I pass the install command.

For example, for the **pylearn-parsimony** library which is not available on Conda, I used this line which worked:

```
system("pip install git+git://github.com/neurospin/pylearn-parsimony.git@master")
```

Comment: The git+git command seems not working anymore. I'm getting a "fatal: unable to connect to github.com" error. "pip install git+https://github.com/neurospin/pylearn-parsimony.git" might be better.